# no consigo utilizar dos componentes en angularjs 1.5

Tags: angularjs, html5

Estoy aprendiendo angularjs 1.5, consigo utilizar un componente, pero cuando quiero utilizar dos, el primero me desaparece y no sé porqué. ¿Alguién se dá cuenta porqué?

</script>-->

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script>
    angular
      .module("appProbandoComponent", [])
      .component("probandoComponent", {
          template: [
            '<div class="miclase">',
            '<span>Esto es algo de HTML en el componente</span> ',
            '<b>Angular Rules!</b>',
            '</div>'
          ].join('')
      });

    angular
      .module("appProbandoComponent", [])
      .component("probandoComponenta", {
          template: [
            '<div class="miclase">',
            '<span>Esto es algo de HTML en el componente2</span> ',
            '<b>Angular Rules!</b>',
            '</div>'
          ].join('')
      });

</script>
```

Mi html5 body ng-app="appProbandoComponent":

```
<probando-component></probando-component>
<probando-componenta></probando-componenta>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al llamar `module("appProbandoComponent", [])` con el segundo parametro reescribes `appProbandoComponent`

Los modulos solo se deben inicializar una ves, para obtener un modulo ya creado usa solo el nombre `module("appProbandoComponent")`

Comment: Efectivamente, era esto. Me tenía esto loca. Muchísimas gracias!